# IndexOutOfBounds with Index 14, size 16. How?

Tags: java, exception, collections, arraylist

How can the index be out of bounds when it actually is in bounds as shown by the stacktrace? Although the context may not matter we are working on a Lua parser/VM for an IDE on the Netbeans platform and this keeps creeping up. How can this be? Some strange concurrency issue? Thanks in advance for any insights.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 14, Size: 16
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.BatchTokenList.existingToken(BatchTokenList.java:197)
    at org.netbeans.lib.lexer.BatchTokenList.tokenOffset(BatchTokenList.java:150)
    at org.netbeans.api.lexer.TokenSequence.offset(TokenSequence.java:256)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.TokenManager.getTokenStart(TokenManager.java:230)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.getCurrentLocation(CompilationUnit.java:459)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.expressionImp(CompilationUnit.java:654)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.expression(CompilationUnit.java:647)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.RHSexpression(CompilationUnit.java:643)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.chunk(CompilationUnit.java:1004)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:164)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupportCompiler.CompilationUnit.compileIfRequired(CompilationUnit.java:148)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.compile(SourcesManager.java:222)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.compileAndEvaluateIfRequired(SourcesManager.java:210)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.addSourceManager(SourcesManager.java:113)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.addDirectory(SourcesManager.java:106)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.addBootDirectory(SourcesManager.java:80)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.addBaseLibraries(SourcesManager.java:72)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.SourcesManager.<init>(SourcesManager.java:47)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.CompilationManagers.GlobalCompilationManager.addProjectDirectory(GlobalCompilationManager.java:76)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.LuaProject.getSourcesManager(LuaProject.java:309)
    at com.MYDevelopers.LuaSupport.LuaProject.LuaProject$ProjectOpenHookImpl.projectOpened(LuaProject.java:599)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.ui.ProjectOpenedHook$1.projectOpened(ProjectOpenedHook.java:84)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.notifyOpened(OpenProjectList.java:1138)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList.access$1600(OpenProjectList.java:134)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$LoadOpenProjects.loadOnBackground(OpenProjectList.java:434)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.OpenProjectList$LoadOpenProjects.run(OpenProjectList.java:312)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1452)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2032)
```

Comment: Context actually matters. Please post some code where you are getting exception.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I checked the ArrayList source. It does appear to be a concurrency issue. The index is checked to be greater than or equal to the size before an exception message is constructed. So, in between the check and the construction of the exception message, at least two more elements seem to be added to the list.

Comment: Concurrency is one explanation. I wonder if anyone can come up with anything else.

Comment: I think it's basically either (a) a concurrency issue, or (b) Something Is Very Broken. :)

Comment: Have you tried to synchronize the access? And is the error reproducible?

Comment: P.S. In terms of "context", posting a stack trace from some internal code that nobody else in the universe has access to is a bit pointless. More relevant would be to explain In Words what your code is doing in general with threading, for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By reading the source of `ArrayList`, you can see that `rangeCheck` is implemented as

```
 private void rangeCheck(int index) {
   if (index >= size)
     throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
 }
```

so my guesses just go to concurrency. There is not other obvious way to have a smaller index while having this exception thrown.

Somehow size changes after that the exception is thrown, in a situation in which

- you try to retrieve an item from the list which is over bounds
- at the same time another thread is adding another element so `size` increases over the size at the time the exception is thrown
- the exception is finally rendered

Comment: No need to involve `ensureCapacity` in this, it didn't have to do anything. `size` is a property that is incremented by `add`, that's the whole story.

Comment: The add method calls ensureCapacityInternal to grow the list itself. So yes, it is absolutely involved, that's why I specified internally.

Comment: No, it isn't. `ensureCapacityInternal` doesn't touch the `size` property at all. It is absolutely irrelevant what else that method may or may not do. By the same logic your advice to increase initial array size is also misguided.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The issue was indeed concurrency, its just bizzare that this particular error kept cropping up. The stack dump itself was displayed in a window instead of the console and perhaps the delay in processing lead to the strange error message. The problem was we made an assumption that the background scanner (indexer) did not start until after the project was done loading. This was not the case and these events happened concurrently, hence each file was scanned twice... at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exception in `sun.print.Win32MediaSize` too, and was helped by the answer, it is a concurrency issue.

Log output:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 14, Size: 15
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at sun.print.Win32MediaSize.findMediaName(Win32PrintService.java:1742)
at sun.print.Win32PrintService.initMedia(Win32PrintService.java:418)
at sun.print.Win32PrintService.getSupportedAttributeValues(Win32PrintService.java:1367)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.updatePageAttributes(RasterPrinterJob.java:548)
at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.setPrintable(RasterPrinterJob.java:997)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPrintServiceExporter.exportReport(JRPrintServiceExporter.java:467)
```

- for the constructor `public Win32MediaSize(String name, int dmPaper)` 
  if **thread 1** add a string to `winStringTable`, but do not add object to `winEnumTable`
- then if **thread 2** call the method `findMediaName`, it will caused the `indexoutofbounds` exception.

Code bellow

```
package sun.print;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.print.attribute.EnumSyntax;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSizeName;

class Win32MediaSize extends MediaSizeName {
    private static ArrayList winStringTable = new ArrayList();
    private static ArrayList winEnumTable = new ArrayList();
    private static MediaSize[] predefMedia;
    private int dmPaperID; // driver ID for this paper.

    private Win32MediaSize(int x) {
        super(x);

    }

    private synchronized static int nextValue(String name) {
      winStringTable.add(name);
      return (winStringTable.size()-1);
    }

    public static synchronized Win32MediaSize findMediaName(String paramString) {
        int i = winStringTable.indexOf(paramString);
        if (i != -1) {
            return ((Win32MediaSize) winEnumTable.get(i));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static MediaSize[] getPredefMedia() {
        return predefMedia;
    }

    public Win32MediaSize(String name, int dmPaper) {
        super(nextValue(name));
        dmPaperID = dmPaper;
        winEnumTable.add(this);
    }

    private MediaSizeName[] getSuperEnumTable() {
      return (MediaSizeName[])super.getEnumValueTable();
    }

    static {
        Win32MediaSize localWin32MediaSize = new Win32MediaSize(-1);

        MediaSizeName[] arrayOfMediaSizeName = localWin32MediaSize
                .getSuperEnumTable();
        if (arrayOfMediaSizeName != null) {
            predefMedia = new MediaSize[arrayOfMediaSizeName.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfMediaSizeName.length; ++i)
                predefMedia[i] = MediaSize
                        .getMediaSizeForName(arrayOfMediaSizeName[i]);
        }
    }

    int getDMPaper() {
        return dmPaperID;
    }

    protected String[] getStringTable() {
      String[] nameTable = new String[winStringTable.size()];
      return (String[])winStringTable.toArray(nameTable);
    }

    protected EnumSyntax[] getEnumValueTable() {
      MediaSizeName[] enumTable = new MediaSizeName[winEnumTable.size()];
      return (MediaSizeName[])winEnumTable.toArray(enumTable);
    }

    }
```

Edit:

i'm doing a print system with 5 thread to call java print api, and got the same exception sometimes. i researched a lot until here i see the concurreny point.
i fixed my problem by init the printService by only 1 thread, i record it here to remind there is concurreny issue in class `sun.print.Win32MediaSize` as i describle above.

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written