# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, runtime-error, indexoutofboundsexception

I use ArrayList to store the 'shadows' for every rectangle in the level but when I iterate through the like this:

```
for(int n = 0; n < shadows.size(); ++n){
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[0]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[1]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[2]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[3]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[4]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(shadows.get(n)[5]);
}
```

I get a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` error that looks like this: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 42, Size: 79`

Why do I get the error even through the index number isn't equal or more than the size? The program still runs like normal but I still don't want it to have any errors.

I have also tried an enchanced for loop but then I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` instead

```
for(Polygon[] polys : shadows){
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[0]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[1]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[2]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[3]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[4]);
 g2d.fillPolygon(polys[5]);
}
```

Comment: Are you modifying this array list in a different thread?

Comment: Does `fillPolygon()` modify `shadows`?

Comment: What is `shadows.size()`?

Comment: try use "volatile" and you might want to use Iterator through the list , and make sure nothing else is modifying your list in the same time , else you will need to use synchronized access

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` when using an enhanced for loop means that another thread is modifying your list while you iterate across it.

You get a different error when looping with a normal for loop for the same reason - the list changes in size but you only check the `size()` constraint at the entry to the loop.

There are many ways to solve this problem, but one might be to ensure all access to the list is [synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html).

Comment: thanks, I just had to move the update method to after the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Are you using more than one thread? [The accepted answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13536340/indexoutofbounds-with-index-14-size-16-how) might help you regarding the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

A ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when you try to modify (edit, delete, rearrange, or change somehow) a list while iterating over it. For example:

```
//This code would throw a ConcurrentModificationException
for(Duck d : liveDucks){
    if(d.isDead()){
        liveDucks.remove(d);
    }
}

//This could be a possible solution
for(Duck d : liveDucks){
    if(d.isDead()){
        deadDucks.add(d);
    }
}

for(Duck d : deadDucks){
    liveDucks.remove(d);  //Note that you are iterating over deadDucks but modifying liveDucks
}
```